# Rails keeps rendering error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I followed some tutorials to create a login system. Everything was working, until I modified something(no idea what) and now rails keeps redirecting me to the 404 page.

This is what I have in the console:

```
    Started GET "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-27 01:24:30 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered errors/error_404.html.haml within layouts/application (12.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 329ms (Views: 323.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

and this is the index:

```
    <h1> User's index </h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.role %> </td>
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words(user.created_at) %> ago</td>
        <td>
          <% if can? :update, @user %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_user_path(user) %>
          <% end %>
          <!-- <% if can? :delete, @user %>
            <%= link_to "delete", admin_user_path(user), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => "Delete #{task.name}" %>
          <% end %> -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>  <%= link_to 'New user', new_admin_user_path %> </p>
```

What other files do you need ? I really don't know what to post.

These are all in controlller/admin

application_controller.rb

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize

  def current_user
    @user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id]) if session[:current_user_id]
  end

  def authorize
    unless current_user
      redirect_to '/login', alert: 'Please login'
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user_from_params, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
..
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize, except: [:new, :create]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]).try(:authenticate, params[:password])
    if @user
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: 'You have successfully signed in'
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'There was a problem with your username or password'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login', notice: 'You have successfully logged out'
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/login' => 'admin/sessions#new'
  get '/logout' => 'admin/sessions#destroy'


  match "/403", to: "errors#error_403", via: :all
  match "/404", to: "errors#error_404", via: :all
  match "/422", to: "errors#error_422", via: :all
  match "/500", to: "errors#error_500", via: :all

  get :ie_warning, to: 'errors#ie_warning'
  get :javascript_warning, to: 'errors#javascript_warning'

  root to: "pages#index"

  namespace :admin do
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :users
  end

end
```

Comment: It is users. I was able to see/edit/add users until I modified 'I don t know what'

Comment: @developer033 That's not true at all. There is no reason whatsoever for your model to be namespaced the same as your controller. Routes and controller namespaces have nothing to do with models or the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your cookies. You are attempting to load stale data from the session:

```
    @user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id]) if session[:current_user_id]
```

You're loading user with id 1 (based on the output in your logs) which no longer exists. You may have dropped and recreated your database or re-run migrations or any number of things that could have destroyed your development data.

The code you use for `current_user` is somewhat naive for precisely this reason. You should handle the case where the user is not found, and destroy the session rather than rendering a 404. You also shouldn't use the `@user` variable; you may wind up overwriting a variable of the same name in your Users controller.

```
def current_user
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id]) if session[:current_user_id]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    session.destroy
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Just edit to `begin`

Comment: Apparently `find_by_id` is causing that I think .... . I checked an session[:current_user_id] is returning 4 but this line gives the error `User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])`

Comment: I think I solved it. I don't fully understand why but if I put '::' before User, like `::User` the problem goes away